# Area of polygons

Tags: geometry, area

I've got a problem that says that I have a triangle with vertices in A, B and C, as the image shows, and the red and the blue surfaces are equal.
[image: Draw]

The question is, how do I say:
"The area of the trapezium (ABDF) less
the area of the triangle (AFE) equals the area of ​​the triangle (DCE)" in an algebraic way?

My teacher uses
$$(ABDF) - (AFE)=(DCE)$$
but I thing a function notation should be also great (the function A is the function "area"):
$$A(A,B,D,F) - A(A,F,E)=A(D,C,E)$$
But, what should I use? (Or what is usually used?) Are both forms correct? Might there be any confusion in the function notation?

Comment: K is sometimes used for area. Additionally, you would probably use the notation $K(ABDF)$, instead of $K(A,B,D,F)$.

Comment: Also, there's not necessairly anything wrong with using words instead of formulas. But otherwise it's probably wisest to use the notation your teacher introduces (as your teacher is supposed to understand yout solution).